# Looping all objects in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of data as follows:

```
var Sonuc = [[{"ID":8,"Number":"1","Name":"Ahmet"}],   
[{"ID":7,"Number":"2","Name":"Semih"}], 
[{"ID":6,"Number":"3","Name":"Derviş"}],  
[{"ID":8,"Number":"4","Name":"Derviş"},{"ID":9,"Number":"4","Name":"Veli"}],
[{"ID":11,"Number":"44","Name":"Zeki"},{"ID":45,"Number":"44","Name":"Veli"}]]
```

I tried to write datas to console for each object as follows, but it does not work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for(var obj in Sonuc[i]) {
          console.log(obj.Number);
      };            
}
```

How can I output the `Number` value for each data on console?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://json.org) but an array of arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have an array or arrays, with the sub-arrays each containing one or more objects.

Your problem is you are not specifying the index for the sub-arrays. You can access the first object like this:

```
console.log(obj[0].Number);
```

That will get you some output at at least, but it is confusing exactly what data you want to get. That 3 loop makes no sense...

If you want to output all objects, then you should first loop the sub-arrays, and then loop the objects. Something like this:

```js
var Sonuc = [[{"ID":8,"Number":"1","Name":"Ahmet"}],   
[{"ID":7,"Number":"2","Name":"Semih"}], 
[{"ID":6,"Number":"3","Name":"Derviş"}],  
[{"ID":8,"Number":"4","Name":"Derviş"},{"ID":9,"Number":"4","Name":"Veli"}],
[{"ID":11,"Number":"44","Name":"Zeki"},{"ID":45,"Number":"44","Name":"Veli"}]];

for (var i = 0; i < Sonuc.length; i++) {
  var arr = Sonuc[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    var obj = arr[j];
    console.log(obj.Number);
  }
}
```